# Oracle SQL SAVEPOINT problems

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently taking an Oracle SQL class and am having problems with SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK.
It is saying that the SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK statements have  invalid syntax near them in vs code and APEX is saying that the SAVEPOINT statements are unknown. If I remove the statements around the code it seems to fix the errors, but it seems like I should be able to do the whole assignment in one file. At least that's what they want. My professor also seems to be stumpded so I'm hoping you guys can help FYI I'm fairly new to coding and SQL. Here is my code:

```
       /*These statements create indexes*/
       CREATE INDEX CD_NUMBER_TRACK_LISTINGS_IDX
       ON D_TRACK_LISTINGS(CD_NUMBER);

       CREATE UNIQUE INDEX EMAIL_D_CLIENTS_IDX
       ON D_CLIENTS(EMAIL);

       CREATE INDEX TITLE_ARTIST_D_SONGS_IDX
       ON D_SONGS(TITLE,ARTIST);
       /* transaction statements*/
       SAVEPOINT one;
       DELETE TITLE
       FROM D_SONGS
       WHERE TITLE = "All These Years";
       INSERT INTO D_SONGS(ID, TITLE, DURATION, ARTIST, TYPE_CODE)
       VALUES(60, "Happy Birthday Sunshine", "4 min" , "The Sunsets", 88);
       ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT one
       COMMIT;

       SAVEPOINT two;
       INSERT INTO D_CDS
       VALUES (100, "Best of Rock and Roll", "Old Town Records", "2004");
       INSERT INTO D_CDS
       VALUES (99, "Party Music", "Old Town Records", "2004");
       INSERT INTO D_CDS
       VALUES (98, "Holiday Tunes for All Ages", "Tunes are Us", "2004");
       INSERT INTO D_CDS
       VALUES (97, "Celebrate the Day", "R and B Inc.", "2003");
       COMMIT;


       SAVEPOINT three;
       UPDATE D_EVENTS
       SET NAME = "Employee Training";
       ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT three;
       /* explain statements*/
      EXPLAIN PLAN   
         SET STATEMENT_ID = 'myPlan'  
         FOR  
         SELECT ID, TITLE, DURATION, ARTIST
         FROM D_SONGS
         WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT DESCRIPTION
            FROM D_TYPES
            WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'Jazz' OR DESCRIPTION = 'Pop');
```

Comment: It’s `delete tablename` (or if you really like typing, `delete from tablename`) - there’s no column list. Also, string literals are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes. I’m not sure what the indexes and `explain plan` have to do with your question.

Comment: Also missing semicolon after first ROLLBACK.

Comment: In real life you just debug this. Start with 1 statement, execute, fix if it fails, undo, add a statement, execute everything, fix if it fails, undo, repeat until done. If you write one larger script with multiple errors you will get unexpected errors that reference some typo earlier. Doing it this way you'll figure out what is wrong: missing semicolons, wrong DELETE syntax, wrong quotes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There issue with rollback statements.

It must be `rollback to <savepoint name>`. `SAVEPOINT` keyword is not required.

In your case, it should be:

```
ROLLBACK TO three; -- or one or two
```

Cheers!!